# Extending MLE Proof to Hold for a $g$ that is Many-to-One

Tags: probability, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

#### Prompt

Show that for the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) $\theta_{MLE}$ of a parameter $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and any differentiable function $g: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, the MLE of $g(\theta)$ is $g(\theta_{MLE})$.

#### Attempt

I've been able to prove this for a bijective (one-to-one) $g$ as follows. However, I am having trouble extending this to a $g$ that is **many-to-one**.

Let $\beta = g(\theta)$ and assume $g$ is one-to-one.

\begin{align}
\theta
&= g^{-1}(\beta) \\
\theta_{ML}
&= \mathcal{L}g^{-1}(\beta) \\
&= g^{-1}(\beta_{ML}) \\
\beta_{ML}
&= g(\theta_{ML})
\end{align}

The above shows that the MLE of $g(\theta)$ is $g(\theta_{ML})$ for a $g$ that is one-to-one.

#### Notes

Please give hints or examples on how to extend this proof for a many-to-one mapping function $g$. Thank you!

Comment: Given a parametric family of probability densities $p(x | \theta)$, how do you define the maximum likelihood estimate of $g$?

Comment: Normally you do not deal with many-to-one functions. If you can re-parameterize the model by a many-to-one function then it is not [identifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability) because multiple $\theta$'s will result in the same distribution. (an example would be if for some distribution you describe the mean by x+y, then multiple combinations of x and y make the same mean)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus is right. If you have $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ that provide different probability distributions while $g(\theta_1)=g(\theta_2)$, parameterizing with $g(\theta)$ is ambiguous.

Comment: @ArnaudMégret I was thinking of the case where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ provide the *same* distribution. The case that you describe is another (equally problematic) case, but it could be solved if we loosen the definitions/descriptions of the $\theta$. If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ provide different probability distributions and are being summarized by a function $g$ for which $g(\theta_1) = g(\theta_2)$ then we would need an additional parameter to describe the distribution....

Comment: .....For instance, if some variable is distributed as $\mathcal{N(\theta, \theta^2)}$ then we *can* speak about the MLE of $\theta$ as well as the MLE of $\theta^2$. It is just that $\theta^2$ is not sufficient to parameterize the distribution (we need the sign as well), but we *can* speak, in some loose sense, of the MLE of $\theta^2$ (in a loose sense, since we should instead speak about the MLE of *two parameters*, and not only of the MLE of $\theta^2$. But sometimes it can be separated, for instance for the normal distribution we can make a MLE for $\mu$ independent from $\sigma$).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus understood. So in your case where $\theta \rightarrow g \rightarrow distribution \rightarrow data$. So we can associate each g with a set of of $\theta$ that provides the same distribution. So, why is it so tricky to prove that max LH is reached for both a value of g and its associated set of $\theta$ ? It seems I totally miss the point. ;-)

Comment: @ArnaudMégret it is not tricky to prove this, it is just not a situation that one normally has. Whenever you are in this sitiuation that "we can associate a 'g' with a set of of $\theta$ that provide the same distribution", then we have the situation that the model is not [identifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability) and we would normally not define a MLE for $\theta$ (we can do it, but the MLE would not be [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Consistency) the likelihood will be a the maximum value for multiple values of $\theta$).

Comment: The only framework how I can imagine this situation is when we are actually dealing with multiple parameters $\theta_1, ... , \theta_n$  and the many-to-one relationship is only the case for the conversion of *one* of those parameters (e.g. for a normal distribution we have two parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and potentially we are only talking about a function $g$ applied to only one of these parameters).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus in the case of Probabilistic Graphical Models with a lot of  parameters.  it is not a problem that they are not identifiable. Usually, they are not.

Comment: *"in the case of Probabilistic Graphical Models with a lot of parameters. it is not a problem that they are not identifiable. Usually, they are not"* In that case how is the MLE defined?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus the set of parameters that maximize the Likelihood of the training sample. We use gradient ascent for that. Actually, usually, we add a regularisation term to the log-LH to avoid overfitting.

Comment: @ArnaudMégret, I see. You are speaking about regularization. But that is different from finding the MLE. Finding the MLE in those cases (without a unique solution) is an ill-posed problem.